# Create an alias for a AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Is it possible to setup a working bucket or to setup an alias for a bucket in AWS S3 CLI console? Because for every single command you have to enter the bucket path and I could't find a solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  It sounds like it might be related to [`aws s3api create-bucket`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html) but it's difficult to determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There IS an `alias` capability for the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). See:

- [AWS re:Invent 2016: The Effective AWS CLI User (DEV402)](https://youtu.be/Xc1dHtWa9-Q?t=1546)
- [GitHub - awslabs/awscli-aliases: Repository for AWS CLI aliases.](https://github.com/awslabs/awscli-aliases)

It can be used to substitute whole commands, but I'm not sure if it can be used to substitute variables within a line. For that, just use your the capabilities of your OS, eg:

```
$ my_bucket=s3://my-bucket/
$ aws s3 ls $my_bucket
```

Comment: super, very useful solution, I used in Windows cmd SET foo=s3://my-bucket/ and then AWS command aws s3 ls %foo%